# wildcard on different tokens in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which looks like this

```
Name
Thomy tyson Olando Magua
```

Using ngram i was able to acheive the wildcard search so that if i type in omy tyson it can return me the above document pretty much similar to this sql query

```
select name from table where name like '%omy tyson%'


PUT sample
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "15"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "typename": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "search": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT sample/typename/2
    {
      "name": "Thomy tyson Olando Magua" 
    }

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.search": "omy tyson"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way in elastic search where i can perform wildcard search on 2 different words separated by other words like

```
select name from table where name like '%omy Magua%'
```

So in this case i would like to perform partial search on first and fourth word.
Any feedback would be helpfull

Comment: can you explain about your mapping. ? how does your documents look like?

Comment: edited the query with document put